# ${PRODUCT_NAME} UNDEFINED error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

After renaming my application I've began to have an issue when I try to build my app.
Build setting PRODUCT_NAME undefined

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Heres a picture:
[image]

Comment: do you use cmake? it has such type of var naming.

Answer (score 12):

This can be fixed by setting the product's name in your build settings. Click on the target you're having issues with, then Build Settings, then search for `product_name` and set it to your application's name.

[image: Screen]